# how can i obtain a cut off value in 5 point likert scale

Tags: terminology

how can i find a cut off value for attitude using a 5 point likert scale where i have 20 statements.The scale ranges from strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree and strongly disagree, each with a value of 5, 4, 3, 2 and 1 respectively. And now i have to categorize it into 2 category by some cut off value into positive and negative. how can i do that?
i have tried to take its median but i am being unable to. please teach me the proper way.

Comment: This question seems to be more about math or possibly implementation as opposed to UX, as you seem to have the 5 values (agree, disagree...) already worked out.

Comment: @DasBeasto - this is the analysis part of UX testing so it may still be a valuable question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is an issue that needs to be solved before you create the scale for your data collection, because it doesn't seem to make sense to try and recategorize it retrospectively since they don't fit in the same proportions.

If you clearly identify one of the responses as being neutral, it then doesn't make sense to try and assign it to a positive or negative response. Perhaps there are other bits of information like comments or additional questions that you can use to verify whether it is an actual neutral response or if it leans towards a positive or negative response.

Depending on exactly what you are trying to report on, and what the processing of that information involves, I think you'll be able to get a more sensible result from your analysis.